# L'emploi de la « pochette » pour le sac ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, synonymes

En français métropolitain est-ce qu'on parle (encore) davantage d'une [*pochette*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pochette) que d'un (petit) *sac* quand on veut transporter un bien qu'on vient d'acheter dans un commerce et est-ce que la pochette a exclusivement la forme d'une enveloppe et est-elle exclusivement en papier ? Peut-on préciser quelle dimension le bien doit-il avoir pour qu'on n'emploie plus « pochette » mais « sac » (un livre, une bouteille de vin, les emplettes au marché) ; en d'autres termes peut-on avoir une « grande pochette » comme synonyme de sac avec des biens courants ? Je me pose la question en me rappelant une anecdote de René Lévesque qui avait demandé un « *petit... sac* » pour y mettre des cigarettes qu'il venait d'acheter et qui s'était fait répondre « [*Monsieur veut une pochette...*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ePYUAAAAYAAJ&dq=ren%C3%A9%20l%C3%A9vesque%20attendez&q=pochette&redir_esc=y) »...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le sac destiné à contenir un achat porte de nombreux noms en fonction du lieu mais pochette n'est pas dans la liste.

[image]

Source: https://francaisdenosregions.com/2016/08/31/les-denominations-du-sachet-plastique/

On peut quand même supposer que là où on appelle ça une poche, la variété de plus petite dimension doit pouvoir s'appeler une pochette.

Pochette est d'autre part utilisé en France pour ce que j'appelle une chemise ou un dossier :

[image]

https://francaisdenosregions.com/2018/08/30/cinq-objets-qui-changent-de-noms-en-belgique-et-en-suisse/

Comment: Vraiment excellentes ces cartes. On peut y [contribuer](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2015/05/18/quel-francais-regional-parlez-vous/). Je ne comprends pas exactement pourquoi _pochette_ ne ressort pas, pourtant on l'a au [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pochette/1) et au [Larousse](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pochette/61907?q=pochette#61208) en ligne, peut-être qu'on est revenu à la source de ce dérivé, ou c'est l'impact du _dossier_ ?

Comment: @Survenant9r7 On trouve le même genre de cartes limitées à la France de l'époque la fin du XIXe siècle ici : http://lig-tdcge.imag.fr/cartodialect3/carteTheme

Comment: Dans la région de Paris on dirait que c'est la totale mais lequel des termes te semble être le plus au centre de la ville ?

Comment: J'entends surtout *sac* ou *sachet* de la part des commerçants. La variété de réponses vient sûrement de personnes donnant le nom qu'ils utilisent dans leur région d'origine, mais pas forcément à Paris ou l'écart à la norme de vocabulaire ou d'accent est souvent stigmatisé ou du moins moqué.

Answer (score 3):

Petite pierre belge à l'édifice de cette réflexion: je n'ai pour ainsi dire jamais entendu personne en Belgique utiliser "poche/pochette" pour "sac" ou 'sachet", à fortiori dans un magasin. Par contre, certains objets bien précis sont en effet désignés avec ce nom, je tente une liste forcément non-exhaustive :

- Une pochette est un petit sac à main, souvent si petit qu'il n'a même pas de bandoulière et qu'on le tient à la main.
- Une pochette-surprise : un petit sac contenant une surprise. Le terme "pochette-surprise" est même un nom à lui tout-seul (cfr [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochette-surprise))
- Le bout de tissu qui dépasse de la petite poche avant d'une veste de costume est également appelé une pochette
- Typiquement, les autocollants à collectionner (type Panini) viennent eux-aussi plutôt en pochettes qu'en sachets
- En cas de transfusion par exemple, on ne dit pas "un sac de sang", mais bien une "poche de sang"

Mais que ce soit pour y placer ses achats, des friandises, des pommes-de-terre et bien d'autres, on parle généralement de sacs ou de sachets.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression en métropole (edit : j'ai surtout vécu dans le sud-est & en région parisienne). On parle plutôt de sac, mais surtout de "sachet" dans le cas d'un petit sac, voire simplement de "petit sac".

Je crois que le terme "pochette" n'est utilisé plus que pour désigner les boites de CD de musique (mais le terme est train de disparaitre avec les CD), ou plus récemment pour décrire un objet entre un petit sac à main, ou un grand portefeuille, généralement destiné aux femmes (par exemple [[ça]](https://www.laredoute.fr/pplp/100/157878/640/648/cat-157931.aspx#srt=noSorting))

Comment: à noter que dans le sud-ouest de la France, les gens utilisent *poche* pour désigner un sachet

Comment: @Flying_whale Une poche pour sachet mais le sachet semble petit, mais une réponse pour le Sud dit _pour désigner un sac_ sans préciser que ce soit forcément petit. L'usage est-il différent entre le Sud et le Sud-Ouest à cet effet ?

Comment: Je crois connaître l'emploi de pochette pour ce qui contient le disque vinyle, pour le CD je pense que je suis familier avec _étui à_ voire avec le terme anglais _case (à)_ mais pas avec l'emploi pour le sac à main. Je suis pas mal certain que Lévesque était à Paris mais je ne peux le confirmer, son livre est publié en 1986 mais l'anecdote se produit certainement bien bien avant.

Comment: Par métonymie, on désigne aussi par le mot *pochette* l'élément visuel (photo ou autre) qui identifie un album ou un single. Par exemple, on peut dire qu'un service de musique en ligne affiche la *pochette* d'un album en cours de lecture, alors que tout est dématérialisé.

Answer (score 2):

Certaines régions de France utilisent 'pochette' pour parler de petit sac. Mais c'est régional, je ne crois pas que ça se dise beaucoup à Paris en parlant d'un sac.

Dans le Berry par exemple (le département de l'Indre) on parle le plus souvent de 'pochon' pour designer un sac plastique dans lequel on met ses courses en sortant du magasin. Mais il arrive qu'on dise 'pochette'.

Comment: Le pochon ce serait comme la poche dont on traite dans une réponse et un commentaire ? Est-ce qu'on dit _une poche_ aussi dans le Berry ?

Answer (score 2):

Habitant dans le sud de la France, je peux dire qu'on utilise le mot 'poche' pour désigner un sac. Pour moi, une pochette, c'est soit une pochette en carton pour mettre des documents, soit une pochette en plastique, qui sera rangée dans un classeur. Mais je ne connais pas le sens qui désigne un sac à marchandises.

Comment: Je présume que le nom _poche_ est féminin. Quand on arrive à la caisse dans un commerce où l'on achète de la nourriture, est-il plus courant de demander/se faire offrir une poche ou un sac ? Je connais la _poche_ mais dans mon monde c'est employé surtout pour un format pour une quantité, surtout de pommes de terre (_une poche de patates_, utilisé aussi dans des emplois figurés) ou peut-être de terre (acheter _une poche de terre_, c'est un gros sac scellé, possiblement un 30kg etc.)...

Comment: Et bien, dans la région toulousaine, tu peux demander une poche pour ranger tes courses, on comprend.

Comment: @Survenant9r7: On [discutait aussi de ça](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1098?m=47912768#47912768) avec [Montée de Lait](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/13100).

Comment: Perso, j'utilise poche et malle. Mais après, chaque région a ses expressions.